# Is it possible to load large non georeferenced pictures in Geoserver?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, wfs-t

I use Openlayers as a viewer of very large pictures, they are tiled and the navigation is exactly what I need.

I also can add a vector layer and draw on it.

But when it comes to save those drawings, saving them online... I can not find anything.

Then I learned about WFS-T and if a map (my picture) and its vector layer are on Geoserver it is possible for the user to draw on it and save the modifications to Geoserver.

Now I can not see how to upload a non georeferenced picture on Geoserver ? I got it up and running but that's it.

At this point I'm such a newbie I don't even know if my combo is the good solution to my problem : drawing with a vector layer on very large pictures and save online the modifications.

Answer (score 1):

Well second hit next to your question in google gives an answer :

http://geo-solutions.blogspot.nl/2011/05/developers-corner-turning-geoserver.html

I do not know if it works properly and if it should be the way to do this properly. You can add image to Openlayers as you used to do (tiled images) and keep the modified vector layer in Geoserver. When necessary you can overlay that vector layer on top of your image.

Comment: I've been through that link also, but they modifyed Geoserver which is too much work for me. I will give a try to your second idea and try to find an openlayer example which save the vector layer in Geoserver. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

or you always can add georeference to file in unkown (local) coordinations system and by this way 'trick' the geoserver. (for example left-upper corner would have coordinates 0,0)

Comment: I will try this, I'm gonna see if QGIS can do it... unless there is something easier. Thanks.

Comment: QGIS will do it just perfect. but arcgis desktop can do it in easier way. :) good luck!